# Minimizing Window after MessageBox

Tags: c#, wpf

I am developing a little applicacion, using Visual Studio 2022, together with .NET 6.0

I have a MainWindow and attached a subordinate Window which I am showing as follows:

```
private void s_Betrieb_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    BetriebWindow betriebWindow = new();
    betriebWindow.Owner=this;
    betriebWindow.Show();
}
```

The subordinate Window BetriebWindow is an ordinary Window, defined in XAML, whitch shows an input-Form (using textBoxes and labels).

After having changed some input, the user clicks on "Close" (the red x in the right upper edge of the Window). I am asking the user wheather he would like to save his changes or not, using a MessageBox.Show().

```
private void Window_Closing(object sender, System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
    {
        if (MessageBox.Show("Wollen Sie Ihre ",...) == MessageBoxResult.OK)
            SaveData();
        Close();
    }
```

After the subordinate Window has closed, the MainWindow is minimizing itself and appears in the taskbar, which I (and perhaps even the future user) don't like.

What am I doing wrong? I want the MainWindow to remain opened on the screen.
But closing the MainWindow should close the subordinate window, too.

Thanks for an answer!

Paul

Answer (score 2):

Remove the call to `Close()` in the `Closing` handler and call `Activate()` on the main window when the child window has been closed:

```
private void s_Betrieb_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    BetriebWindow betriebWindow = new();
    betriebWindow.Owner = this;
    betriebWindow.Closed += (ss, ee) => Activate();
    betriebWindow.Show();
}
```

---

```
private void Window_Closing(object sender, System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
{
    if (MessageBox.Show("Wollen Sie Ihre ", ...) == MessageBoxResult.OK)
        SaveData();
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! it works!

Comment: @Paulus: You're welcome. Please [accept](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86978/how-do-i-accept-an-answer-on-stackoverflow) the answer.